# Changing Text in PHP

Tags: php, string, text

I haven't found anytihng in Google or the PHP manual, believe it or not. I would've thought there would be a string operation for something like this, maybe there is and I'm just uber blind today...

I have a php page, and when the button gets clicked, I would like to change a string of text on that page with something else.

So I was wondering if I could set the `id=""` attrib of the `<p>` to id="something" and then in my php code do something like this:

```
<?php
    $something = "this will replace existing text in the something paragraph...";
?>
```

Can somebody please point me in the right direction? As the above did not work.

Thank you :)

**UPDATE**

---

I was able to get it working using the following sample:

Place this code above the `<html>` tag:

```
<?php
$existing  = "default message here";
    $something = "message displayed if form filled out.";
    $ne = $_REQUEST["name"];

    if ($ne == null) {
      $output = $existing;
    } else {
      $output = $something;
    }
?>
```

And place the following where ever your message is to be displayed:

```
<?php echo $output ?>
```

Comment: Um... are you looking to do this with javascript? or is the page reloading and PHP is putting out a new page with the changed text?

Comment: i have a php page, and when the user clicks a button on that page, a piece of text on that page will be changed.

Comment: You need to look into javascript. php can't do anything after the page has been outputted.

Comment: yeah it sounds like JS task. but one cannot tell for sure

Comment: I still have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: That's funny. You're implying there's something wrong with the way I asked the question, however it must have been sufficient as the people who posted answers seemed to have understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can get from your very fuzzy question, usually you don't need string manipulation if you have source data - you just substitute one data with another, this way:

```
<?php
    $existing  = "existing text";
    $something = "this will replace existing text in the something paragraph...";
    if (empty($_GET['button'])) {
      $output = $existing;
    } else {
      $output = $something;
    }
?>
<html>
<and stuff>
<p><?php echo $output ?></p>
</html>
```

but why not to ask a question bringing a real example of what you need? instead of foggy explanations in terms you aren't good with?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. The code in your answer didn't work, it just kept displaying the 'existing' message. However, after editing/removing parts of it, I got it to work. I've updated my question to include what worked. Thanks :)

Comment: @j-t-s, Very ugly.  You should be ashamed.

Comment: What's so ugly about it? I'm only new to PHP. And btw, my version is not very different from @Col's at all. I assumed it that it would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the content of the paragraph without reloading the page you will need to use JavaScript. Give the paragraph an id.`<p id='something'>Some text here</p>` and then use innerHTML to replace it's contents. `document.getElementById('something').innerHTML='Some new text'`.

If you are reloading the page then you can use PHP. One way would be to put a marker in the HTML and then use str_replace() to insert the new text. eg `<p><!-- marker --></p>` in the HTML and `$html_string = str_replace('<!-- marker -->', 'New Text', $html_string)` assuming $html_string contains the HTML to output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for string manipulation and conversion you can simply use the `str_replace` function in php.

Please check this: [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a form (which I'm assuming you do) just check if the variable is set (check the `$_POST` array) and use a conditional statement. If the condition is false then display the default text, otherwise display something else.